# Codedui UWP WaitForControlExist gives UITestControlNotFoundException

Tags: c#, uwp, automation, coded-ui-tests

I'm using codedui to test a xamirin desktop app
The test runs fine when I use Playback.Wait(2000) but this not efficient as I need to accurate result for test case taken time so I used UiCodedControl.WaitForControlExist();
But when I debug the test this line gives me: UITestControlNotFoundException

```
XamlWindow.Launch("Viu.OPGFELApplication_zf8xyq721yjt6!App");
                //Playback.Wait(2000);
                this.UIMap.FMELogWindow.LoginPanel.UIItemCustom1.DISN.WaitForControlExist();
                this.UIMap.FMELogWindow.LoginPanel.UIItemCustom1.DISN.Text = "123456S";
```

Comment: The question title says `WaitForControlReady` but the body says `WaitForControlExist`. Please [edit] the question to make your question clear. Additionally, please show the line(s) of code containing the `WaitForControl...` call.

Comment: @AdrianHHH Thanks for your tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is waiting for the `...DISN` UI object to exist, but it is likely that one of its parents also does not exist when the `Wait...` is called.

Some "belt and braces" code would wait for each of the parent controls, as follows:

```
this.UIMap.FMELogWindow.WaitForControlExist();
this.UIMap.FMELogWindow.LoginPanel.WaitForControlExist();
this.UIMap.FMELogWindow.LoginPanel.UIItemCustom1.WaitForControlExist();
this.UIMap.FMELogWindow.LoginPanel.UIItemCustom1.DISN.WaitForControlExist();
```

However, the first one or two `Wait...` calls above are probably not needed. Without knowing the application I would suggest that only one `Wait...` should be needed and it is probably on either `LoginPanel` or `UIItemCustom1`.

Comment: Thanks alot this is actually works as u said the first wait before the DISN wait did the trick but it seems I will keep trying with other components too until it works out .. I couldn't upvote this because I'm not yet eligible to do so but I really appreciate it (Y)